# Android - GestureDetection force closing app

Tags: java, android, swipe, gesture

I tried adding a `GestureDetector` in my app, so that when the user swipes from left to right, it goes to the next activity, and when the swipe right to left, the previous. Now, before doing that I wanted to test it using toasts. I built the code and tested it, but it just crashes when I simply touch the screen. I don't even have to swipe. Here is my code:

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

 import java.io.File;

 import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;

 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
 import android.view.GestureDetector;
 import android.os.*;


 public class Softkeys extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnGestureListener{

 private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
 private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.themes);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Softkeys.this, this);
        OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

        ll.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

        int [] viewIds = new int [] {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7, R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.b10, R.id.b11, R.id.b12, R.id.b13, R.id.b13, R.id.b14, R.id.b15, R.id.b16, R.id.b17, R.id.b18, R.id.b19, R.id.b20, R.id.b21, R.id.b22, R.id.b23, R.id.b24, R.id.b25, R.id.b26, R.id.b27, R.id.b28, R.id.b29, R.id.b30};
        for(int i = 0; i < viewIds.length; i++){
            View v = findViewById(viewIds[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
        Button stock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        stock.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_stock);
        Button stockBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        stockBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_stock_blue);
        Button green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        green.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_green);
        Button pink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
        pink.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_pink);
        Button purple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
        purple.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_purple);
        Button yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
        yellow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_yellow);
        Button red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
        red.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_red);
        Button galaxy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
        galaxy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_galaxy);
        Button galaxyBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
        galaxyBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_galaxy_blue);
        Button reflect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
        reflect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_reflect);
        Button reflectBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b11);
        reflectBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_reflect_blue);
        Button razor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b12);
        razor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_razor);
        Button razorBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b13);
        razorBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_razor_blue);
        Button small = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b14);
        small.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_small);
        Button smallBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b15);
        smallBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_small_blue);
        Button smallReflect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b16);
        smallReflect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_small_reflect);
        Button smallReflectBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b17);
        smallReflectBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_small_reflect_blue);
        Button xperia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b18);
        xperia.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_xperia);
        Button blueXperia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b19);
        blueXperia.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_xperia_blue);
        Button zte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b20);
        zte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_zte);
        Button zteBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b21);
        zteBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_zte_blue);
        Button college = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b22);
        college.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_college);
        Button collegeBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b23);
        collegeBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_college_blue);
        Button defused = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b24);
        defused.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_defused);
        Button defusedBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b25);
        defusedBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_defused_blue);
        Button droid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b26);
        droid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_droid);
        Button droidBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b27);
        droidBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_droid_blue);
        Button pixel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b28);
        pixel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_pixel);
        Button pixelBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b29);
        pixelBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_pixel_blue);
        Button facebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b30);
        facebook.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soft_facebook);
        int [] viewIds2 = new int [] {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7, R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.b10, R.id.b11, R.id.b12, R.id.b13, R.id.b13, R.id.b14, R.id.b15, R.id.b16, R.id.b17, R.id.b18, R.id.b19, R.id.b20, R.id.b21, R.id.b22, R.id.b23, R.id.b24, R.id.b25, R.id.b26, R.id.b27, R.id.b28, R.id.b29, R.id.b30};
        for(int i = 0; i < viewIds2.length; i++){
            View v = findViewById(viewIds2[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent a = new Intent(Softkeys.this, Bmod.class);
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b1) {
        a.putExtra("Stock", "stock");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b2) {
        a.putExtra("StockBlue", "stockblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b3) {
        a.putExtra("Green", "green");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b4) {
        a.putExtra("Pink", "pink");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b5) {
        a.putExtra("Purple", "purple");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b6) {
        a.putExtra("Yellow", "yellow");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b7) {
        a.putExtra("Red", "red");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b8) {
        a.putExtra("Galaxy", "galaxy");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b9) {
        a.putExtra("GalaxyBlue", "galaxyblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b10) {
        a.putExtra("Reflect", "Reflect");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b11) {
        a.putExtra("ReflectBlue", "reflect");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b12) {
        a.putExtra("Razor", "razor");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b13) {
        a.putExtra("RazorBlue", "razorblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b14) {
        a.putExtra("Small", "small");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b15) {
        a.putExtra("SmallBlue", "smallblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b16) {
        a.putExtra("SmallReflect", "smallreflect");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b17) {
        a.putExtra("SmallReflectBlue", "smallreflectblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b18) {
        a.putExtra("Xperia", "xperia");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b19) {
        a.putExtra("XperiaBlue", "xperiablue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b20) {
        a.putExtra("Zte", "zte");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b21) {
        a.putExtra("ZteBlue", "zteblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b22) {
        a.putExtra("College", "college");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b23) {
        a.putExtra("CollegeBlue", "collegeblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b24) {
        a.putExtra("Defused", "defused");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b25) {
        a.putExtra("DefusedBlue", "defusedblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b26) {
        a.putExtra("Droid", "droid");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b27) {
        a.putExtra("DroidBlue", "droidblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b28) {
        a.putExtra("Pixel", "pixel");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b29) {
        a.putExtra("PixelBlue", "pixelsblue");
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.b30){
        a.putExtra("Facebook", "facebook");
        startActivity(a);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

        Toast.makeText(Softkeys.this, "Right to left",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("tag", "Right to left");
        return true; // Right to left

    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

        Toast.makeText(Softkeys.this, "Left to right",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("tag", "Left to right");
        return true; // Left to right
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    Intent in = new Intent(Softkeys.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}


@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
        float arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
}
```

}

Sorry, it's sorta big. Anyways, here's the log:

```
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/InputEventReceiver(3256): Exception dispatching input event.
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at com.cydeon.plasmamodz.Softkeys.onTouchEvent(Softkeys.java:282)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2413)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2120)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-10 22:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3256):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.cydeon.plasmamodz.Softkeys.onTouchEvent(Softkeys.java:282)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2413)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2120)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-10 22:34:28.229: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized `gestureDetector` which is a local variable of `onCreate()`.

Just remove this keyword `final GestureDetector`

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.themes);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Softkeys.this, this);

    /* Your stuff */

}
```

Comment: Dang. That's the second time I forgot to initialize something or used the same variable twice, leaving it uninitialized. Thanks man!